# Woocommerce REST API add_filter not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created an API to add new cart item data using API. I think filter is not working in code.

Registered Route :

```
register_rest_route(
        'ecm-api', '/setGiftMessage/',
        array(
            'methods'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => array($this,'setGiftMessage')
        )
    );
```

defination of function:

```
public function setGiftMessage($request){
    global $woocommerce,$sitepress;

    $woocommerce->frontend_includes();
    
    $lang = $request['lang'];
    $user_id = $request['user_id'];
    $product_id = $request['product_id'];       
    $written_message = $request['written_message'];
             

    if(empty($user_id)){
        $response['status'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = __('User id is required', self::domainText);
        $response['data'] = new stdClass();
        return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);
    }

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    
    $woocommerce->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    $woocommerce->session->init();
    $woocommerce->customer = new WC_Customer( get_current_user_id(), true );
    $woocommerce->cart = new WC_Cart();
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data',function($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) use($request) {
            
            $cart_item_data['msg_on_gift']='wish you happy birthday';
            return $cart_item_data;
        }, 10, 3 );

    $woocommerce->cart->persistent_cart_update(); 
    
    
        $response['status'] = $cart_item_data;
        $response['message'] = __("Gift Message to saved", self::domainText);
        return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

    
}
```

I also tried to **register the filter as a separated function**:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data',array($this,'add_gift_message_to_cart'),10, 3 );
public function add_gift_message_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) 
{ 
    $cart_item_data['msg_on_gift']='wish you happy birthday';
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: You should not include a function inside a function…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have try as separate function too.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Not possible to say anything else useful with the provided code and information…  Just remember that `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` is trigered on "normal" `add_to_cart()` method *(not Ajax)*…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have sent data from REST API. I want to add this data to cart_item_data. Code is written inside filter not executed in REST call.